# Variable in Javascript Object set by this

Tags: javascript

I recently came across some Javascript where a variable is being set within a method. It's never declared other than with `this`. The following is a *very* simplified example:

```
'use strict'
var object = {
    property1: 'value',
    method: function() {
        this.variable = this.property1;
    },
}

object.method();
```

`this.variable` is used throughout the object in other methods, but is is never declared with either `var` or `let` and it isn't an `object[key]`.

Are there any risks to passing around a variable this way?

Comment: `it isn't an object[key]` It *will be*, as soon as `object.method` is called.

Comment: there's no risk to do so. object usually work with dynamic key value.

Comment: before `object.method`, `object['variable']` is `undefined`, that means you can use that after you define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no risk in passing the variable this way, until unless you run the object.method() first. If not done then, object.variable will return you undefined.
Here you can check it like this:

```js
var object = {
    property1: 'value',
    method: function() {
        this.variable = this.property1;
    },
}

console.log(object.variable);
object.method();
console.log(object.variable);
```

The console.log(object.variable); that was called before object.method(); will print undefined.
Your code can also be written as below and it will behave the same:

```js
var object = {
    property1: 'value',
    method: function() {
        object['variable'] = this.property1;
    },
}

object.method();
console.log(object.variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `object.method();` then it will associate a new property `variable` to the `object` prototype and when you do `object['variable']` it will return you the value so it is not necessarily required to declare `variable` prior to setting it's value. You can access it using `object[key]`. Thus, there is no risk using this way.

```js
var object = {
    property1: 'value',
    method: function() {
        this.variable = this.property1;
    },
}

object.method();
console.log(object['variable']);
```